# Solve in integers.

Tags: integers

Solve in integers:

$3x - 3y = xy - 5$
$y^2 = 5x + 6$
$1+p+p^2+p^3=3^n$

> For second, i think that infinite number of solutions.
>
> Maybe $x = 5$ $n^2 - 8 n + 2$, $y = 4 - 5 n$, n element $\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### $(1.)$

$$3x - 3y = xy-5$$
$$3x - xy -3y = -5$$
$$x(3-y)+3(3-y) = 4$$
$$(x+3)(3-y) = 4 $$
$$(x,y) = (-2,-1) \,\, ,(-1,1)\,\, ,(1,2) \,\, , (-4,7) \,\, ,(-5,5) \,\, , (7,4)$$

#### $(2.)$

This equation has infinitely many solutions over integers.

#### $(3.)$

First we check that the trivial case $ p = n = 0$ which satisfies the equation.
$$1+p+p^2+p^3 = 3^n$$
$$(p^2 + 1)(p+1) = 3^n$$

Let $(p^2 + 1) = 3 ^q$ and $(p + 1) = 3^r$
Then ,

$$p^2 + 1+ p+1 = 3^q + 3^r$$
$$ p(p+1) + 2 = 3^q + 3^r$$

Now notice that R.H.S is divisible by $3$ , implying that L.H.S is also divisible by $3.$ This is only possible if $ p^2 + p \equiv 1\mod 3.$ But it is easy to observe that there is no value of $p$ satisfying this relation . Hence the only possible solution is $(0,0).$

Comment: Good job, thats right

Comment: But look, in third, how we can have answer 3k+2 if we have equation x,y = (0,0). 3k+2 != 0, if k integer

Comment: @Mikey_mouse where is $x$ and  $y$ in $3^{\text{ rd }} equation ?$

Comment: oh no, of course not x and y. p,n = (0,0)

Comment: @Mikey_mouse I still don't see how they are a solution.

Comment: 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 3^0 = 1

Comment: @Mikey_mouse **You have edited the question and now it reads as $3n$ instead of $3^n$ !** Also is $p$ any integer or does it denote a prime number .

Comment: Omg, really i just want to add space.... sorry. p is any integer

Answer (score 0):

$$x=\dfrac{5-3y}{y-3}=\dfrac{5-3(y-3)+9}{y-3}=-3+\dfrac{14}{y-3}$$

So, $y-3$ must divide $14$

As $(y,5)=1$

If $y=5z\pm1$

$$5x+6=25z^2\pm10z+1\iff x=5z^2\pm2z-1$$

What if $y=5z\pm2$